# Swift - Firebase Database query range of items

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following database tree:

```
root: {
    followees: {
        <uid-1> : {
            // list of all users "uid-1" is following (each child node is a different FCM topic)
            <uid-1-1>: true, // true = subscribed to FCM topic
            <uid-1-2>: false,
            // theoretically, "uid-1" could be following millions of users, but 100k is probably a more reasonable maximum
        }
        <uid-2> : {
            // list of all users "uid-2" is following
        }
    } 
}
```

What would be the most efficient and memory-saving method to iterate all children in `subtree`?

I've created a recursive solution using a limiting query that reads 1000 children at a time. This works, but due to the recursive aspect, all children are stored in memory until the base case it hit; it's essentially the same as loading all children at once.

I've thought of clearing out the collection returned by `observeSingleEvent(.value)`, but that doesn't work because the collection is immutable.

The best solution I can think of is to query the database for the first 1000 children, then the second 1000, and so on:

```
query(startIndex:0, endIndex:999)
query(startIndex:1000, endIndex:1999)
query(startIndex:2000, endIndex:2999)
...
```

How can this be done using Firebase? Can it be done at all? Should my database structure be redesigned so a subtree can't contain millions of entries?

Any advice is appreciated!

P.S. Here's my recursive solution if you're interested. Note it's not valid Swift code -- it just shows the concept.

```
func iterateChildren(startingAt: String, block: (child) -> Void) {
    // The actual query would use queryStartingAt and queryLimited.
    ref.query { children in
        // Used in recursive call.
        var nextStartingId: String? = nil

        for (index, child) in children.enumerated() {
            if (UInt(index) == limit - 1) {
                // Firebase Database's queryStarting(atValue:) method is inclusive of
                // atValue, so skip the last item as it will be included in the next
                // iteration.
                nextStartingId = child.key
                break
            }
            block(child)
        }

        if (nextStartingId != nil) {
            self.iterateChildren(startingAtId: nextStartingId, block: block)
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify as to why you need to iterate over a (possibly) million child nodes whose values are boolean? Typically you iterate to find something or detect a match that cannot otherwise be found via a query? What would that be in this case.

Comment: It's an unlikely scenario, but theoretically possible. Each child node refers to  a person whose Firebase Messaging topic the client is subscribed to. When the user logs in/out, their subscriptions need to be setup/torn down.

Comment: Hmm, that structure may not be well suited for the task then. I am understanding.. subtree in your example is the messaging topic and the users are all of the users, and the ones with a true value are subscribed and the ones with false are not. Is that correct? It may help us formulate an answer if we have a bit more detail and an actual firebase structure. As it is, it's not clear why the iteration is needed. Oh and why would their subscriptions be torn down upon logging out?

Comment: I've updated the structure with some context. It is my understanding that FCM subscriptions are tied to the device, and upon logout, user should be unsubscribed from their FCM subscriptions in order to prevent receiving notifications while logged out.

Comment: Typically if the user has subscribed to a topic, you can simply *-unsubscribeFromTopic:* when they log out. Or maybe you are doing that? You would typically keep a list of subscribed topics per user /users/uid_0/subscribed/topic_0, /topic_1 etc. Which is typically a small list.

Comment: Right, that's what I am doing (and what I meant by "teardown"). I'm wondering how to handle it if it's not a small list.

Comment: If it's a few thousand topics you could easily load those into memory via .value and iterate over them and unsubscribe from each. That's what I would recommend. Even if it's 10k nodes, it's a tiny amount of data; just a series of key:value pairs with the value being the topic name. Alternatively you can leverage .childAdded to iterate over them individually and unsubscribe but .value is the way to go. Also, the example data structure in your question would be  a lot smaller as you are only storing topics the user is subscribed to - the false nodes would not be needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154936/discussion-between-cohenadair-and-jay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a single big child, try to use small and concise child. Why you don't try to group your sub child with some logic?

A nice solution might be to group data by insertion date (but depends of your use case):

```
root : {
   child : {
      "20/09/2017" : {
          "uid" : true  
      },
      "21/09/2017" : {
          "uid" : false
          "uid" : true
      }
   }
}
```

With this solution you could iterate your child node with `observe(.childAdded)` where every completionHandler give you a small block of data.

Anyway, what I'm sure is that using a `.value` observer is a bad solution.

Firebase suggest to avoid god child, so try to follow this simple rule: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data

Comment: Why is using .value a bad solution if I just want to get the data for a one-time use and be done with it? `observe(.childAdded)' sets up a permanent observer (which is not what I want), and `observeSingleEvent(.childAdded)` would only give me a completion handler for one item (I think).

Comment: You can disable the observer when you have finished reading all data. take the first and last node of the child, and when your .childAdded read the last you can stop your observer.

However, of course you can use a observeSingleEvent of type .value but depends on what you have to do.

So if you need to read the data once, yes you can use. But if you think to have millions of child the problem is on your data structure

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding how `.childAdded` works. If I want to iterate through a nodes children, observing `.childAdded` is useless if no children are added. In my case, no children are being added, they're already there.

Comment: The first invocation of .childAdded iterate over all child of the node your are observing. So the first time working like a for loop over your node. At the end the observe will be invoked just when new data will be added to the node

Comment: Interesting. So in the case of the structure you suggested, wouldn't invoking an `observe(.childAdded)` on "child" still load all date-keyed nodes into memory? Or does it only retrieve one node at a time from the database?